# How do I output an entry author's data

Tags: templating

I have a blog. I want to output an entry author's first and last name. What is a good method to accomplish this?

Comment: Is "author" a reserved term in Craft CMS? I made a field called "author" but it is returning my name (I'm the one who typed the entries in) instead of the author of the article I'm entering.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For each entry, you can get the username of the author by simply using {{ entry.author }} (assuming entry is the variable containing the blog entry).

If you want to display Full name, first name and/or last name for one entry, you'd use:

```
{{ entry.author.fullName }}
{{ entry.author.firstName }}
{{ entry.author.lastName }}
```

For a list of entries and their authors, you'd use:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('your-section').find() %}
    {{ entry.author.fullName }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
{{ entry.author.firstName }} {{ entry.author.lastName }}
```